# JSF dataTable logic: I am retrieving multiple rows of the same entity from the db; however i want to show only one

Tags: java, sql, jsf, datatable, xhtml

I am retrieving a table of data from my db which looks like:

![1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzI2j.jpg

As you can see that I have the **same EmpName, EmpID, Designation repeating**. This is because this **same person has that many tasks allocated to him.** 
To make it look **more presentable** i would like the EmpID, Name, Designation printed only once and the rest of the rows of the particular employee printed as many times as in db.

my DataTable looks like:

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{employeeWiseReportBean.empWiseList}" var="u" rendered='true'
                     styleClass="infoTable" headerClass="dataTableHeader"   rowClasses="dataTableRow">

                     <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        Employee ID
                        </f:facet>   
                         #{u.empID}   
                    </h:column>

                         <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        First Name
                        </f:facet>   
                         #{u.fullName} 
                    </h:column>

                         <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        Designation
                        </f:facet>   
                       #{u.designation}
                    </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        Task ID
                        </f:facet>   
                         #{u.subTaskID}
                    </h:column>

                         <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        Task Description
                        </f:facet>   
                         #{u.taskDescription}
                    </h:column>

                   <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        From
                        </f:facet>   
                         #{u.fromDate}
                    </h:column>

                   <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        TO
                        </f:facet>   
                         #{u.toDate}
                    </h:column>

                     </h:dataTable>
```

I know why it is printing so many instances, but i dont understand how do i make it print only one instance.

The query that I used and the result set is like:

```
   public List<EmployeeDutySchedule> getEmpWiseDB()
{
     List<EmployeeDutySchedule> empDutyList=new ArrayList<EmployeeDutySchedule>();

   ResultSet rs=null;
   String query="Select employee_duty_schedule.emp_id, first_name, last_name,  emp_designation, task_allocated_id, description, from_date, to_date\n" +
" FROM transport_department_schema.employees_information,  transport_department_schema.employee_duty_schedule, transport_department_schema.m_subtasks\n" +
" Where employees_information.emp_id=employee_duty_schedule.emp_id AND  employee_duty_schedule.task_allocated_id=m_subtasks.subtask_id  ;\n" +
"\n" +
"";
    System.out.println(query);
     rs=MyQueryExe.executeQuery(query);


            System.out.println("rs "+rs);
            try
        {
        while(rs.next())
        {
         EmployeeDutySchedule empDuty=new EmployeeDutySchedule(); 
          empDuty.setEmpID(rs.getString("emp_id"));
         empDuty.setFullName(rs.getString("first_name")+" "+rs.getString("last_name"));

         empDuty.setSubTaskID(rs.getString("task_allocated_id"));
         empDuty.setTaskDescription(rs.getString("description"));
         empDuty.setDesignation(rs.getString("emp_designation"));
         empDuty.setFromDate(rs.getDate("from_date"));
         empDuty.setToDate(rs.getDate("to_date"));

         empDutyList.add(empDuty);
            System.out.println("size of list  "+empDutyList.size());

          }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return empDutyList;
}
```

The database table itself has multiple empID entries for show all the tasks allocated to the particular employee.

Any help would be dearly appreciated!  I hope my question is clear enough.
**Thank You.**

Comment: Can you edit your question with your output screenshot ?

Comment: I am not sure about the question you have asked but you can use distinct in your query get the unique results so your values are not repeated.

Comment: @Bhola Read the question . it is clearly mentioned `i would like the EmpID, Name, Designation printed only once and the rest of the rows of the particular employee printed as many times as in db.`

Comment: @sankrish well that cant be achieved in datatable as every entry is a row and it will show all the data for that paticular row. you cannot manipulate the row.

Comment: @sankrish i have added a link of the output first thing. Please check it out

Comment: then how am i supposed to show it in a better presentable manner? Right now it looks very messy

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, the header strings "Employee Id", etc. are repeating or the number of the rows related to each Employee?

In the latter case try adding Distinct keyword into your query:

```
 Select distinct employee_duty_schedule.emp_id, ................
```

Comment: yes, i want the rows related to each employee to show the name, id and designation of the employee only once; HOWEVER, i want the taskid, description, from and to date to be shown in different rows only.